# How to retrieve last command?

Tags: terminal, kali-linux

I downloaded the new version of kali linux and I have a problem in the terminal. First it is not showing me the directory before the `$` and now when I press on the left, right, up and down keys to retrieve the last command used in the history it’s showing `^[[A` .

Can someone help me?

I have tried to edit in the shortcuts of the terminal but it didn’t work.

I created a user that can have access to sudo.

Comment: I think this issue depends on what terminal you're using, so additional info would  be helpful

Comment: This is often a matter of selecting the right login shell - see for example [Arrow keys, Home, End, tab-complete keys not working in shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-home-end-tab-complete-keys-not-working-in-shell)

Comment: Once you get past choosing the shell then you can configure your `.bashrc` if need be. [Here is some help](http://bashrcgenerator.com/) if you don't know how

Comment: Kali Linux is generally discouraged for anyone other than professional security experts.  I expect you're going to give yourself a world of pain if you keep trying to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you edited something before in `/etc` before that because the default params for the prompt are read from `/etc/bashrc` (then from  `/etc/profile.d` if exists) and it must have line like this: `PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$"`for the default promt (user, hostname, working directory) also  for the history - there must be a line `history -a` for parallel history between the  terminal sessions. And here is some  addition information  what happens when you log in [What happens when we login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438150/scripts-in-etc-profile-d-being-ignored)

To replace a broken `.bashrc` you can use `/etc/skel/.bashrc`

Comment: so i don't know if it is broken but i don't have the history when i press history i don't have the kali@kali ... how should i repair the .bashrc ? i press in the terminal /etc/skel/.bashrc ? and i haven't touched the etc

Comment: Replace the content of `/etc/bashrc` with the content of `/etc/skel/bashrc` . If this does no fix the issue you can try to boot from liveusb and take the files from there(I have not tried it) or reinstall it (without formatting the `/home` and keeping your data )